# How would I re-write this coin flip loop

Tags: powershell

I have a question that has been puzzling me for a little while

I have a small script that gives the results of flipping 4 coins

```
foreach  ($a in (0,1)){
    Foreach ($b in (0,1)){
        Foreach ($c in (0,1)){
            Foreach ($d in (0,1)){
                Write-host $a," ",$b," "$c, " ", $d
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How could I re-write this so that you enter the number of coins to use? i.e. 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good candidate for a recursive function definition:

```bsh
function Flip-Coins {

    Param(
        $Number,
        $result = @()
    )

    foreach  ($a in (0,1)) {
        if ($Number -eq 1) {
            Write-Host ($result + $a)
        } else {
            Flip-Coins -Number ($Number-1) -result ($result + $a)
        }
    }
}

Flip-Coins -Number 8
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could generate them like this:

```bsh
# Set number of coins
$n = 4

# Generate the initial sets (of flips) we want to calculate the product of 
$sets = ,@(0,1)*$n

# Start out with the list only containing the initial set of coinflips
$list,$rest = $sets

foreach($set in $rest){
    # For every remaining set of coinflips, add to each of the existing string of flip sequences
    $list = foreach($item in $list){
        $set |ForEach-Object {$item,$_-join ' '}
    }
}

# Now contains all the combinations
$list
```

This will work for any number of coinflips greater than two, but beware that with 20 coins that's `2^20`, iow. **more than one million flip sequences**